# Camera & Photo Library Permission - Handle when a user does not accept to allow iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, ios10

I am requesting users to accept access to both photo library and camera use.  I would like to be able to handle the case for when a user does not accept, but I am having issues doing so.  Here is the code for when I check user permission:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { granted in
        if granted {
            if(!self.captureSession.isRunning){
                self.setupCustomCamera()
            }
        } else {
            self.takePhotoButton.alpha = 0.5
            self.takePhotoButton.isEnabled = false
            self.showNeedAccessMessage()
        }
}
```

And my `showNeedAccessMessage()` as follows:

```
func showNeedAccessMessage() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Settings", message: "Please adjust your device settings to grant access to camera use.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        show(alert, sender: nil)
}
```

The issue here is that when the `granted` case is not met, I would like to show an alert.  Instead of my alert showing, my application attempts to open the 'Image Settings' page, which shows up as follows:
[image]

Is there a default handling for this case?  If so, any ideas how I would go about fixing the black 'Image Settings' screen?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
                if granted == true
                {
                    // User granted
                }
                else
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "This app is not authorized to use Camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Setting", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                                UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
                            }
                        }
                    }))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    return
                }
            });
```